# transforming a matrix in R by

Tags: r, recursion, matrix, operation

I want to make a new matrix B from a previous matrix A, where the length of rows and columns are the same in B and every position corresponds to a ranking of A.
In particular, for any x of a location [i,j] in A, I want to find how many values are greater than [i,j] (which sum(A>x), which I can find when x is discrete, but not for any x), followed by division by the total number of observations*variables in the matrix A.
I think using the apply function would be able to create matrix B as I wish, but I'm having trouble finding a way to apply use of "sum" for each position (i.e., sum(A>x)/# of positions in A. 
I think I could use apply(A, c(1,2), FUN(X...)), but I do not know what function I can use.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short version:**  `matrix((length(M) - rank(M))/length(M), nrow=nrow(M), ncol=ncol(M))`

**Long version:** 
`length(M)` will give you the number of elements in the matrix.
`length(M) - rank(M)` will give the number of elements greater than each element.
So you want `(length(M) - rank(M)) / length(M)`   but formatted into a matrix like M, so

```
matrix((length(M) - rank(M))/length(M), nrow=nrow(M), ncol=ncol(M))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, great explanation!